# deja-dup fails to restore home directory

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, backup, restore, deja-dup

I backed up my home directory with deja-dup, installed Ubuntu 13.04, and attempted to restore the files, but after chosing the date of the backup to restore and chosing the location where to put the files, I get a "Failed with an unknown error" message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1412, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1405, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1339, in main
    restore(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 630, in restore
    restore_get_patched_rop_iter(col_stats)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 522, in     Write_ROPaths
    for ropath in rop_iter:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 495, in integrate_patch_iters
final_ropath = patch_seq2ropath( normalize_ps( patch_seq ) )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 475, in patch_seq2ropath
    misc.copyfileobj( current_file, tempfp )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/misc.py", line 166, in copyfileobj
    buf = infp.read(blocksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/librsync.py", line 80, in read
self._add_to_outbuf_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/librsync.py", line 94, in _add_to_outbuf_once
raise librsyncError(str(e))
librsyncError: librsync error 103 while in patch cycle
```

I tried to restore earlier backup points, but all of them fail. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 again and tried to restore from there (to have the same version of deja-dup etc.), same problem. Any ideas how I could rescue my data? By now, I'm pretty desperate.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it by now?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are not selecting correct folder (as I was). Try>> [Is it possible to restore only one directory with the backup utility?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181272/is-it-possible-to-restore-only-one-directory-with-the-backup-utility)

Apparently the "/home " directory is not possible in deja dup but the /home/user is available.