# Nautilus + Deja Dup: no menu item for "File -> Restore Missing Files..."

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, backup, 16.10, duplicity

I'm trying to explore my files that have been backed-up with Duplicity/Deja Dup. My understanding is that the "`File -> Restore Missing Files`" menu item comes from the `ubuntuone-client` package ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/181276/155341)), but that package is not available anymore.

So what is the current way to integrate Deja Dup and Nautilus? Is there another package that provides this menu item in questions?

Comment: hopefully, with Ubuntu's change from Unity back to Gnome, it will work again, see https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/Revert - has anyone tried whether it works under 17.10?