# Selective Restore from a Deja Dup backup?

Tags: nautilus, backup, restore, deja-dup

I regularly backup my drive with Deja Dup. Today I have noticed that I have accidentely deleted some files, and wanted to restore them from a recent backup. However, I can't seem to find the "Restore Missing Files" option that was once present in Nautilus (either in the File menu, or in the right-click menu).

I am currently on Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/181276/274932). Beware that if you right-click on a file you're offered "Revert to Previous Version..." instead of "Restore Missing Files...". To easily click outside of a file you may need to temporarily switch to icon view instead of list view.