# Failed to acquire the VirtualBox COM object on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I had VirtualBox 4.3 installed and uninstalled it to have VirtualBox 5.1... big mistake, ever since I keep getting errors, or being unable to install any 
other version. Already used Synaptic, and

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
```

following a suggestion, used the command

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
apt-get autoremove
```

which seemed to get rid of some VB dependencies and allowed me to install VB again, but I get this error when I try to start it:

```
Failed to acquire the VirtualBox COM object. 
The application will now terminate. 
Failed to acquire the VirtualBox COM object. 
The application will now terminate. 
Document is empty.   
Location: '/home/user/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml', line 1 (0), column 1.


/home/vbox/vbox-5.1.22/src/VBox/Main/src-server/VirtualBoxImpl.cpp[550]
(nsresult VirtualBox::init()).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) 
Component: VirtualBoxWrap
Interface: IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} Callee:
IVirtualBoxClient {d2937a8e-cb8d-4382-90ba-b7da78a74573}
```

What should I do?

Comment: You must COMPLETELY uninstall ALL of vbox before attempting to install another version. The method of uninstalling depends entirely upon how you originally installed that version - apt/synaptic can remove ONLY packages they installed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I encountered this situation after a power loss and reboot of my host system.

### Overview

VirtualBox stores its global configuration in `~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml`*, (if you've upgraded from early versions it may be in `~/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml`*).  The file includes global configuration options and the list of registered virtual machines with pointers to their XML settings files (for each machine under `~/VirtualBox VMs`).

### Options

To solve a corrupted `VirtualBox.xml` do one of the following, in order of preference:

1. **Restore a backup.** Ubuntu comes with [Backups (Déjà Dup)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup) installed by default. If you're using it, you can easily restore the file by navigating to `~/.config/VirtualBox/`, right-clicking on `VirtualBox.xml`, and choose *Revert to previous version...*   [more details](https://askubuntu.com/a/181276/139249)
2. **Restore a copy.** Each time VirtualBox Manager starts up, it creates a backup copy of `~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml` (called `~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml-prev`). The drawback is this file will/may only be useful if you haven't started VirtualBox Manager.

   **Steps to restore a copy**

   1. Ensure VirtualBox Manager is not running.
   2. Navigate to `~/.config/VirtualBox/`
   3. Rename `~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml` to something like `~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml-original`
   4. Rename the backup `~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml-prev` to `~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml`
   5. Start VirtualBox Manager. This is a copy of the state of the *last VirtualBox Manager startup,* and hopefully resolves your situation.
3. **Remove the file.** Always Backup first, including `VirtualBox VMs`.   This is a last resort.

   **Steps to remove the file**

   1. [Backup](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/HowItWorks)
   2. Navigate to `~/.config/VirtualBox/`
   3. Delete/rename the `VirtualBox.xml` file.
   4. Start  **VirtualBox Manager**.  This will recreate a file during startup.
      The result of removing the file will likely be a loss of some/all of your machines in the list. Any missing machines might be able to be restored by re-registering `.vbox` files and `{snapshot}.vdi` files stored by default in the `~/VirtualBox VMs` folder.  Full details of how to recover this condition are beyond the scope of this question.  Always

**Notes:**

- The tilde (`~`) is a shortcut representation for the `$HOME` environment variable. It can be cut-and-paste into a GUI program like [Gnome Files (Nautilus)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) (which supports freedesktop.org conventions), or in a terminal.

  - To past a path in the location bar of `Gnome Files (Nautilus)`, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>. Then type or paste a path.
- Before upgrading: It is prudent to `shutdown` each virtual machine (in lieu of a `suspended\snapshot` state).
- Before upgrading: It is also important to `eject/unmount` any `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` in CD drive. Then, new version can be inserted and installed after upgrade.

Comment: Mine `/home/myuser/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml` was completely empty x) , so I've copied contents from `/home/myuser/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml-prev` into it as you've suggested and it worked! :)

Answer (score 8):

I faced the similar issue, removing the xml file resolved this for me. So for you please do

`rm /home/user/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml`

and start virtualbox again.

Comment: I'd suggest moving instead of removing. ;-) Always better practice to have a backup in case things don't go as expected. Try: `mv /home/user/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml ~/` --> which will move `VirtualBox.xml` to your `$HOME` folder. 

Alternatively, use a GUI File Manager such as Gnome Files (originally Nautilus) to remove to Trash or move somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

All of this was very helpful. Thanks very much.

I tried using the "prev" version, which didn't work. Then moved VirtualBox.xml to a backup and started up VirtualBox.
That showed a new, empty system with no VMs.
I started up each of the VM's by right-clicking and "open with Virtualbox".
They started up as before and are now available in the VM list when I open Virtualbox.